# Df.drop/delete duplicate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I drop the exact duplicates of a row. So if I have a data frame that looks like so:

```
A    B    C
1    2    3
3    2    2
1    2    3
```

now my data frame is a lot larger than this but is their a way that we can have python look at every row and if the values in the rows are the exact same as another row just drop or delete that row. I want to take in to account for the whole data frame i don't want to specify the column I want to get unique values for.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) method:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  2
2  1  2  3

In [24]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[24]:
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  2
```

Comment: This is the simpler way to do it now I realize, thanks @MaxU!

Comment: @bernie, Pandas' API is very rich, so usually we can achieve the same thing in quite a few different ways ;-)

Comment: I have tried that it doesnt work it is still showing duplicates for some reason

Comment: @Cannon, can you provide a __reproducible__ data set?

Comment: I actually just used df.duplicated().sum and apparently I don't have duplicates. I am having the problem with how I am bringing the data in so a couple columns are different I did'nt look close enough. Sorry about that guys I just thought that the df.drop_columns wasn't working

Answer (score 2):

You can get a de-duplicated dataframe with the inverse of [`.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df[~df.duplicated(['A','B','C'])]
```

Returns:

```
>>> df[~df.duplicated(['A','B','C'])]
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  3  2  2
```